# usb ethernet cable

Tags: drivers, usb, ethernet

Does anyone know how to connect a ubuntu laptop to the internet via USB and ethernet?

I tried to connect my Sony vaio laptop to the internet via an ordinary USB-ethernet-cable but it turns out I (and the rest of the world) are lacking a driver for the cable (sitecom). It seems that the same kind of Belkin cable has the same problem: no drivers for ubuntu.

The thing is i blew up my ethernetcard in the laptop (sony vaio) so USB is my only possibility. without wanting to offend you but i guess the only other alternative is installing windows and that would be bad wouldnt it ;)

thanks in advance for your replies

Answer (score 0):

You can search online, there are some sites that list compatible Hardware:
https://h-node.org/ethernetcards/catalogue/en/1/1/undef/undef/yes/USB/undef/undef?search_string=&submit=Search

They should run ootb without any driver Installation.

There is also a database on the ubuntu wiki here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsWiredNetworkCards

Comment: thanks for the replies! Do you happen to know more of these websites as the cables mentioned on h-node.org are not available in my country. and indeed there are a lot of adapters out there, just not many are working with ubuntu

Comment: Just added a link.

Comment: Please set my answer as answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many USB ethernet adapters out there.  Most of them will probably work, although I haven't gone and poked for specific hardware compatibility

However, you're going to be somewhat limited.  An Ethernet over USB adapter is limited by the speeds of USB.  If you have a gigabit USB-to-Ethernet device, connected to a gigabit network, you're actually going to be limited to 480 Megabits a second (for USB 2.0), or possibly slower. Keep this in mind going forward.